# Next largest integer with some middle bits matching a pattern?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

My input is:

- a bit mask `mask` of width `n` and some offset `k` >=0
- a bit pattern `pattern` with 1s in some (but not necessarily all) the positions where the bit mask has 1s.
- an integer `val`

I want to find the next largest integer `result` such that:

- `result > val`
- `result & mask == pattern`

For example, suppose `mask = 0xFF00` and `pattern = 0x0100`. Then we expect the following result:

```
NextLargest(mask, pattern, 0x00000) => 0x00100
NextLargest(mask, pattern, 0x000FF) => 0x00100
NextLargest(mask, pattern, 0x010FE) => 0x001FF
NextLargest(mask, pattern, 0x010FF) => 0x10100
```

Another example -- say `mask = 0xF` and `pattern = 0xF`. Then we expect:

```
NextLargest(mask, pattern, 0x20) => 0x2F.
```

I've tried something like "strip out the bits that `mask` cares about, increment it, OR back in `pattern` and return" but I keep hitting edge cases. The problem is something like a generalization of finding the next largest multiple of some integer.

Here's my attempt so far (runnable link: https://ideone.com/AhXG5M):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using uint32 = unsigned long;

uint32 NextLargest(int width, int offset, uint32 mask, uint32 pattern, uint32 val) {
    unsigned long long ret = (val + 1) & ~mask;
    if ((ret & ((1 << (offset + 1)) - 1)) == 0) {
        // "carry" across the mask
        ret += 1 << (offset + width);
    }
    return ret | pattern;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int width = 12;
    int offset = 4;

    uint32 significant_bits = (1 << (width + 1) - 1) << offset;
    uint32 wanted_bits = 0xFFF << offset;

    cout << hex;
    // want 0xFFF1 -- correct
    cout << NextLargest(width, offset, significant_bits, wanted_bits, 0) << endl;
    // want 0xFFF2 -- correct
    cout << NextLargest(width, offset, significant_bits, wanted_bits, 1) << endl;
    // want 0x1FFFF0 -- incorrect, get 0xFFF0
    cout << NextLargest(width, offset, significant_bits, wanted_bits, 0xF) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it true for `val & mask` to be equal to `pattern` as well?

Comment: @Ron Presumably because this is being done in C++? This is relevant because different languages could provide different bit manipulation functions even if they’re mostly the same, or perhaps there’s a useful library function or something. Why *wouldn’t* it be relevant?

Comment: `NextLargest(mask, pattern, 0x010FF) => 0x101FF` shouldn't that be `=> 0x10100`?

Comment: There's not a single piece of code in there that isnt c++ either

Comment: The `=>` was just marking the expected output. I have some code but it's sloppy, let me paste it in.

Comment: Added my attempt, which doesn't work. I thought it might be clearer not to include it since it's so far off the mark.

Comment: @Severin -- no, that's not a requirement.

Comment: Isn't `NextLargest(mask, pattern, 0x010FE) => 0x001FF` supposed to be `0x10100`, `0x001FF<0x010FE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the `value` broken into 3.
The bits above the mask, in the mask and below the mask.
`H(value)`, `M(value)`, `L(value)`.

We know `M(result)==pattern`.
We have three candidates.

C1 is `H(value)+pattern+0`.

C2 is `H(value)+pattern+L(value)+1`

C3 is `H(value)+pattern+X`

`X==(mask<<1)&~mask`. That is the lowest bit above the `mask`.

If `pattern>M(value)` we can use C1.
Reducing the high-bits will get a number `<value` and setting any low bits will increase the number.

If `pattern==M(value)` then we can try C2 which is actually `value+1`.
That fails if adding one overflows to the pattern bits.

That means all the low bits are set and the next lowest place to add is the first bit above the mask.

```
unsigned next_masked(unsigned mask,unsigned pattern,unsigned value){
    unsigned reduced_pattern=(mask&pattern);//May not be required...
    unsigned over_add=(mask<<1)&~mask;
    unsigned upper_mask=~(over_add-1);
    unsigned cand=(value&upper_mask)|reduced_pattern;
    if(cand>value){
        return cand;
    }
    if((value&mask)==reduced_pattern){
        unsigned scand=value+1;
        if((scand&mask)==reduced_pattern){
            return scand;
        }
    }   
    return cand + over_add;
}
```

Here it is again with some unit tests:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned next_masked(unsigned mask,unsigned pattern,unsigned value){
    unsigned reduced_pattern=(mask&pattern);//May not be required...
    unsigned over_add=(mask<<1)&~mask;
    unsigned upper_mask=~(over_add-1);
    unsigned cand=(value&upper_mask)|reduced_pattern;
    if(cand>value){
        return cand;
    }
    if((value&mask)==reduced_pattern){
        unsigned scand=value+1;
        if((scand&mask)==reduced_pattern){
            return scand;
        }
    }   
    return cand + over_add;
}

bool invariant_next_masked(unsigned mask,unsigned pattern,unsigned value,unsigned result){
    if((result&mask)!=(pattern&mask)){
        return false;
    }
    if(result<=value){
        return false;
    }
    for(unsigned test=result-1;test>value;--test){
        if((test&mask)==(pattern&mask)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int check_next_masked(unsigned mask,unsigned pattern,unsigned value,unsigned expect){
    unsigned result=next_masked(mask,pattern,value);
    if(result!=expect){
        std::cout << std::hex << mask << ' ' << std::hex << pattern << ' ' << std::hex <<value << "==" << std::hex <<result << "!=" << std::hex <<expect <<'\n';
                return 1;
    }
    if(!invariant_next_masked(mask,pattern,value,result)){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int errors=0;

    errors+=check_next_masked(0xFF00,0x0100,0x0000,0x00100);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0xFF00,0x0100,0x00FF,0x00100);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0xFF00,0x0100,0x10FE,0x10100);        
    errors+=check_next_masked(0xFF00,0x0100,0x1067,0x10100);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0xFF00,0x0100,0x10123,0x10124);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0xFF00,0x0100,0x110FF,0x20100);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0xFF00,0x0100,0x102FF,0x20100);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0xFF00,0x0100,0x101FF,0x20100);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0x000F,0x0007,0x10123,0x10127);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0x000F,0x0007,0x10128,0x10137);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0x0FF0,0x0230,0x10128,0x10230);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0x0FFF0,0x01230,0x01231,0x01232);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0x0FFF0,0x01230,0x41237,0x41238);
    errors+=check_next_masked(0x0FFF0,0x01230,0x4123F,0x51230);


    if(errors>0){
        std::cout << "Errors "<< errors << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Success\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test this, but the following algorithm should work (pseudocode):

```
let mask, pattern, and val be inputs
let fls be function that finds last bit set in word
let ffs be function that finds first bit set in a word

let applied be (val & ~mask) | pattern
if applied is greater than val then
    return applied
let low_order_mask be (1 << ffs(mask)) - 1
if applied == val then
    let flipped_low be (~value & low_order_mask)
    if not flipped_low then
        return applied + 1 // no need to carry
// need to carry
let set_low_zero be applied & ~low_order_mask
let carry be 1 << (fls(mask) + 1)
return set_low_zero + carry
```

`fls` and `ffs` are provided by POSIX, but other systems might not do so. There are answers on SO for how to implement these if you need to.

Comment: Awesome, this looks very reasonable. I'll expand my implementation and update the answer with the full version. `fls` and `ffs` are neat, I've never seen that before.

For `any_low_zero = value ^ low_order_mask; if not any low zero then` -- that can be simplified to `if value == low_order_mask`, right? So that whole branch can become `if applied == val == low_order_mask then return applied + 1`. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @PatrickCollins your conclusion is reasonable, but it awakens me to the fact that my code is buggy. The point is to test whether any of low order bits is zero, and ignore rest. There is a mask operation missing.

Comment: @PatrickCollins should be better now. Also, my ffs, fls usage was lacking essential shift operations.

Comment: If (val&~mask)|pattern > val you can clear the low-bits and return `applied & ~low_order_mask`. Otherwise I believe this is almost the logic I offered. For example Mask 0x0FF0 Pattern 0x0200 and value 0x3045. Applied is 0x3205 but 0x320**0** satisfies the requirements and is smaller.

Comment: @Persixty yeah, I would not be surprised if I overlooked something. In fact, I dislike the approach that I took a bit. If I had time, I would rewrite such that I shift left side non-masked bits over the masked bits, add 1, then shift the left side back and finally apply the pattern. Best thing about that is no branching.

Comment: @user2079303 I don't quite understand that but it is worth noting that unless there's some structure the branch where the pattern matches the existing bits and the low bits are all 1 could be one comparison and is 1:2^(n+k) with n and k as OP. For the sizes of n & k in the examples that is a rare branch unless some bias exists.

Answer (score 0):

is the problem to calculate the *LARGEST* or *SMALLEST* next value?? the largest value seems odd to be. if the requirement is to calculate the smallest value, I think this code should work: (tested on gcc 7.1, assuming a 64 bit target, sizeof(void *) == sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(uint64_t))

```
size_t next_smallest_value (size_t mask, size_t pattern, size_t x) {
    assert(pattern & mask == pattern);
    // only change bits within mask range to meet the requirement
    auto y = x & ~mask | pattern;
    if (y > x) {
        // if the operation increased the value
        // mask off all the lower bits
        auto lsb_mask = __builtin_ctzll(mask);
        return y & ~ones(lsb_mask);
    } else {
        // otherwise, the operation decreased or didn't change the value
        // need to increase the fraction higher than the mask
        auto msb_mask = 63 - __builtin_clzll(mask);
        // higher part cannot be empty if the masked part decrease
        assert(msb_mask < 63);
        auto higher = ((y >> msb_mask) + 1) << msb_mask;
        // also higher part cannot overflow
        assert(higher != 0);
        return y & mask | higher;
    }
}
```

the idea is very simple: divide the bits into 3 parts: higher part, masked part, lower part. the masked part can be derived directly from and is determined by the `mask` and `pattern`, it cannot be other values.

after calculating the masked bits, if the value increase, just mask off all bits in the lower part. otherwise, increase the higher part by 1 (and also mask off all the lower bits).

the above code doesn't deal with ill-formed input, it will trigger the assertions, but the checks are not exhausted.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a requirement in my use case that I find the next largest rather than the next smallest. Thanks for your work, though.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by the term *next largest value*? your example isn't clear to me, like in the first example in the question: given `mask = 0xff00` and `pattern = 0x0100`, you stated `NextLargest(mask, pattern, 0x00000) => 0x00100`, I believe the (32 bits) *largest* `0xffff01ff` is *NOT* what you want, but wouldn't `0x01ff` be larger than `0x0100` and still meet the requirement in this sense? same for the second example, should it be `0x0100` or `0x01ff`? and the third example simply is not greater than the input. that's why I am confused. or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is two functions for this little bit confusing question
First function gives the largest next integer that fulfills the requirements for the result.
Second one gives SMALLEST next value.

---

1: Get the LARGEST integer which satisfies `result & mask == pattern` and `result > val`:

```
unsigned NextLargest (unsigned mask, unsigned pattern, unsigned val) {

    // zero "mask" bits and set "pattern" bits in largest (unsigned) int
    unsigned const x = ~mask | pattern;

    // if result is not greater than val, we can't satisfy requirements
    if (x <= val) {
        ... report error, return error code or throw something
    }

    return x;
}
```

Obviously this just returns highest (unsigned) integer value that meets the requirements `result & mask == pattern` and `result > val`. The if-clause checks if result will not be greater than `val`, and the function will fail.

---

2: Get the SMALLEST next value after `val` that meets the requirements:

```
unsigned NextSmallest (unsigned mask, unsigned pattern, unsigned val) {

    unsigned const x = (val + mask + 1) & ~mask | pattern;

    if (x <= val) {
        ... increment wrapped, can't give greater value
    }

    return x;
}
```

edit: Changed `(val|mask)` to `val+mask` because the result must be still greater than `val`.

This function calculates `val + 1` and carrying overflowing bits over `mask`'d bits.
Here are few examples what the function does, if `mask = 0x0ff00` and `pattern = 0x00500`:

```
val        +mask    +1       &~mask     |pattern == result

0x00000    0x0ff00  0x0ff01  0x00001    0x00501
0x00001    0x0ff01  0x0ff02  0x00002    0x00502
0x000fe    0x0fffe  0x0ffff  0x000ff    0x005ff
0x000ff    0x0ffff  0x10000  0x10000    0x10500
0x00100    0x10000  0x10001  0x10001    0x10501
0x0f000    0x1ef00  0x1ef01  0x10001    0x10501
0x0ff00    0x1fe00  0x1fe01  0x10001    0x10501
0x0ffff    0x1feff  0x1ff00  0x10000    0x10500
0x10000    0x1ff00  0x1ff01  0x10001    0x10501
0x10001    0x1ff01  0x1ff02  0x10002    0x10502
0x100ff    0x1ffff  0x20000  0x20000    0x20500
```

After long editing and rewriting I still can't give good enough answer for the question. Its examples has weird results. I still leave this here, if someone finds these functions or parts of them useful. Also I did not actually tested the functions on the computer.